# Timer tick event is automatically disabled by Picturebox paint event

Tags: c#, events, timer, picturebox

I am using a timer to record the location of clicks I perform in a picturebox for a specified amount of time that is timed by the timer. As a next step I added PictureBox paint event to show small circles where I hit in the pictureBox. It works perfectly but timer ticks somehow becomes disabled. Next I noticed that if I comment out the following line from the FORM     InitializeComponent() function, timer starts working:

```
this.pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Paint);
```

Here is the timer1 and picturebox1 settings from InitializeComponent() function:

```
this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        this.timer1.Interval = 1000;
        this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this.pictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
        this.pictureBox1.Image = global::Omers_project.Properties.Resources.img_002;
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(282, 158);
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(694, 492);
        this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
        this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Click);
        this.pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Paint);
```

Also Timer1_Click and PictureBox1_Click functions are given below:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        passes--;
        textBox_time_passed.Text = passes.ToString();
        if (passes == 0)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Time is up"); 
        }

    }

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs eM = (MouseEventArgs)e;
        temp_storage.x = eM.X;
        temp_storage.y = eM.Y;

        myList.Add(temp_storage);
        count++;
        textBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(count);

    }
```

Hence I can use only one of them at a time but unable to use both functionalities at the same time. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Please show how you are creating the timer.

Comment: your timer statement access to same picture box? if can please include your timer code related to the picture box? or you try to delegate the part you access the picture box either inside time or the Paint event?

Comment: Here is the portion of code regarding creation and setting of timer (in InitializeComponent() function):

  
this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            this.timer1.Interval = 1000;
            this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);

Comment: Do not put code in comments, click the edit button and update your question.

Comment: @V-SHY Yes it accesses the same Picturebox. There is only one picturebox and there is a start button, when I press this button timer starts and until its stops, all the clicks in the picturebox are stored in a list. So in the picturebox_Click callback function I store mouse click locations.

Comment: can you try to comment textBox_time_passed.Text = passes.ToString(); and change MessageBox.Show to Console.WriteLine("Time is up"); and check if your timer event is triggered from console output? I wonder your timer stuck at Main UI access

Comment: I try embedded my paint event with your timer, I found that my timer always work properly, if can please provide your paint event statement also so that I can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what your code looks like but I would suggest to execute timer `Start()` method instead of `Enable = True`.

Also... are you doing any code on the PictureBox paint event in a different thread?

If it still doesn't work, please provide more code so we can have a better idea.

Cheers